# hi all! i'am getting the following error while executing the application.please help me out

Tags: php, zend-framework

Fatal error: Uncaught Run time Exception: Unable to load application. - Type `composer install` if you are developing locally. - Type `vagrant ssh -c 'composer install'` if you are using Vagrant. - Type `docker-compose run zf composer install` if you are using Docker.

Comment: Highlight your error in a blockquote, or with code tags, and fix the title: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Before to post a question on SO you should go through [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Finally, if you are sure your question fits the rules, read [How to Ask a question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a useful, well formed and on-topic question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply read --"

> - Type `composer install` if you are developing locally.
> - Type vagrant `ssh -c 'composer install'` if you are using Vagrant.
> - Type `docker-compose run zf composer install` if you are using Docker.

Comment: Nope.i've already installed the composer in my project folder.

Comment: What are you trying to load? cause if it doesn't fix you should take a look at permissions!